# How to rigorously show that the maximum variance of an hermitian matrix is $\left( \frac{h_{max}-h_{min}}{2} \right) ^2$?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, hermitian-matrices

Suppose we have an hermitian matrix $H$ with eigenvalues $h_i$, and I want to get the minimum value of its variance, i.e. $\vec{v}^{\dagger}H^2\vec{v}-\left( \vec{v}^{\dagger}H\vec{v} \right) ^2$. How can we rigorously show this?

I tried Lagrange's multiplier method which I think nearly succeed. By spectral decomposition, we can write $H$ as $H=\sum_i\lambda_i|i\rangle\langle i|$(let me use $|i\rangle$ to stand for column vectors while $\langle i|\equiv|i\rangle^\dagger$). Then the problem changes into minimize $$\sum_i{{h_i}^2}\langle v|i\rangle \langle i|v\rangle -\left( \sum_i{h_i}\langle v|i\rangle \langle i|v\rangle \right) ^2.$$
over unit vectors $|v\rangle$.

By replace $\langle v|i\rangle \langle i|v\rangle $ with $p_i$, we finally state the problem as
$$
\underset{p_i}{minimize}\sum_i{{h_i}^2}p_i-\left( \sum_i{h_i}p_i \right) ^2
\\
s.t. \sum_i{p_i=1}
$$
Now we can start Lagrange's multiplier method. By introduce $\lambda$, we have the Lagrangian is $\sum_i{{h_i}^2}p_i-\left( \sum_i{h_i}p_i \right) ^2+\lambda \left( \sum_i{p_i}-1 \right) $, by derivative w.r.t. $p_i$ we have the linear equation:
$$
{h_k}^2-2\left( \sum_i{h_ip_i} \right) h_k=\lambda ,\forall k
\\
\sum_i{p_i}=1
$$
We then solve those equations and maybe it might have some easier results by noticing that $\lambda$ only has one value which does not change with different $h_k$.

For example, if we have $p_1$ to $p_3$, we can solve this by writing it in matrix form:
$$
\left( \begin{matrix}
 1&  1&  1&  0\\
 2h_1h_1&  2h_2h_1&  2h_3h_1&  1\\
 2h_1h_2&  2h_2h_2&  2h_2h_3&  1\\
 2h_1h_3&  2h_2h_3&  2h_3h_3&  1\\
\end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c}
 p_1\\
 p_2\\
 p_3\\
 \lambda\\
\end{array} \right) =\left( \begin{array}{c}
 1\\
 {h_1}^2\\
 {h_2}^2\\
 {h_3}^2\\
\end{array} \right) 
$$
Is there some easier way to solve it? I can't directly see the answer and using Gaussian elimination seems too complicated for more variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need to solve the linear equations totally but do mind one important truth: $\lambda$ only has one value while we have several restrictions. Keep this in mind and mind that ${h_k}^2-2\left( \sum_i{h_ip_i} \right) h_k=\lambda $ is parabola w.r.t. $h_i$, hence we can only allow two $p_i\neq0$, or only one. Then it's easy to show that the optimal case is when $p_{max}=p_{min}=\frac{1}{2}$.